# keypressevent no detecta la tecla enter pyqt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

una pregunta sencilla estoy tratando de detectar la tecla enter de mi teclado al presionarla pero no funciona. este es el codigo que utilizo:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import Qt


class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)


    def keyPressEvent(self,event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter:
            print("pressed")
        event.accept()



app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#Key-enum) hace referencia a la tecla <kbd>INTRO</kbd>/<kbd>ENTER</kbd>  del **teclado numérico** por norma general, debes usar en su lugar `QtCore.Qt.Key_Return`:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
        ...
```